# Xamarin Profiler Error on Android (Runtime is too old)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, xamarin-profiler

Xamarin Profiler does not work for Android. I have Visual Studio Enterprise (required for Xamarin Profiler). I am currently attempting to test profile a Microsoft application which builds fine.

Test Project GitHub: https://github.com/davidortinau/Xappy

Attempted numerous emulated and real devices. I get the following error message:

`XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:23:05.6658] Error occured on run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio`

My log file:

> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.7818] ##########################################
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.7828] # Xamarin Profiler version -  1.6.10.15
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.7828] #  * Arch x86_64
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.7828] ##########################################
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.8669] initializing android platform
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.8689] initializing ios platform
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.8689] initializing mlpd platform
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:40.9429] processing command line = --options=name:pixel_2_pie_9_0_-*api_28,gc:sgen,maxframes:8 --type=android --device=pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 --target=com.microsoft.Xappy|crc6419cf9c8281e18cce.SplashActivity --device=pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 --options=name:pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28
> XamarinProfiler.Core.ProfilerService Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.8548] processing command line = --options=name:pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28,gc:sgen,maxframes:8 --type=android --device=pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.Core.WindowsRunFactory Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.8778] Creating android run for com.microsoft.Xappy|crc6419cf9c8281e18cce.SplashActivity target on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.8888] Initializing profiling...
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9088] Waiting for device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 to connect
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9108] StartRecording for com.microsoft.Xappy
> XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Android.ProfileAndroidRun Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9268] checking runtime version on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9608] Stopping application com.microsoft.Xappy.crc6419cf9c8281e18cce.SplashActivity
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9748] Application com.microsoft.Xappy.crc6419cf9c8281e18cce.SplashActivity stopped
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9778] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9778] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9778] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9858] Error occured on run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-*api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
> XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2021-07-13 11:22:53.9858] Error occured on run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device pixel_2_pie_9_0*-_api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio

Xamarin Studio is now defunct, so this log message is not very helpful to me. I have attempted devices as old as API 23 (6.0 Marshmallow). Any ideas on how to get Xamarin Profiler working?

Answer (score 1):

Update visual studio to 2022 and uninstall profiler and re install from visual studio Tools -> 'Get tools and features..' menu.

Comment: This works for me. Xamarin Profiler was updated to version 1.8.0.22

Answer (score 0):

> Error occured on run com.microsoft.Xappy: Runtime installed on device
> pixel_2_pie_9_0-_api_28 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer
> version of Xamarin Studio

From the error log,you can try the following methods:

1. update your visual studio to a newer version.(e.g. the latest
   version).
2. If the problem persist,download Xamarin Profiler with a new version
   , the link
   is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/tools/profiler/release-notes/1.6/1.6.13

Comment: I am using Profiler version - 1.6.10.15, which is the most up to date Windows release. The release versions that exceed 1.6.10 are for Mac. Still not working.

Comment: This is a known issue, you can check it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Profiler-reporting-runtime-insta/1430599.

Comment: Also this one: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XamarinProfiler-Runtime-installed-is-to/1415138

Comment: Also this one: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Profiler-does-not-work-with-Visu/1690229 but this problem does not resolve for Visual Studio 2019